# MySQL value embedded within HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

I am trying to open a page and send `$username` (which I got from MySQL) through a URL parameter. The value is not sent to `AddPage.php` as it is embedded in the PHP/HTML. I think there is something wrong with the syntax but i could not figure it out.

The following is the code of the hyperlink:

```
<?php           
echo"<h2 > Please try to <a href='AddPage.php?id=" . $username . "'>Add</a> again</h2>";
?>
```

Can someone look at it and tell me where is the problem?

Comment: when you get to AddPage.php, is the username in the url?

Comment: you may need to do `$username = $_GET['username'];` if your PHP configuration doesn't automatically do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Justin! its working now after I added this code $_GET['username'];  it was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Are you sure `$username` is populated by the mysql query? Try a `var_dump($username)` just before your link to see what and better, if the variable is populated.

2 - Is the variable send in the URl?

3 - A typo: there is no space between `echo` and `"`

4 - In AddPage.php did you use `$_GET['username']` to get the username?

On the side: why do you call you variable user- *name* when in fact it's an *id* ?

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help. When you're able, pleas accept the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

```
At first get the value from url parameter like:
<?php $username = $_GET['username']; ?>
<?php          
echo '<h2 > Please try to <a href="AddPage.php?id='.$username.'">Add</a> again</h2>';
?> 

OR

<h2 > Please try to <a href="AddPage.php?id=<?php echo $username ;?>">Add</a> again</h2>
```

Comment: all you have done is brake the correct html syntax by removing a sing quote

Comment: You removed a crucial single quote resulting in the href-attribute not being closed properly!